# In Thunderbird/Lightning, can I change the sending identity when inviting attendees to an event?

Tags: email, thunderbird, lightning, caldav

I use several sending identities in Thunderbird, e.g. `a@mail.example.net`, `b@mail.example.net`, and `c@mail.example.net`. I have one calendar for each of these sending identities: `A`, `B`, and `C`. That is, the email address selected in Properties for the `A` calendar is `a@mail.example.net`, the email address selected in Properties for the `B` calendar is `b@mail.example.net`, and the email address selected in Properties for the `C` calendar is `c@mail.example.net`.

The `a` identity is my default sending identity.

I created a new event in Lightning and selected the `C` calendar. I and clicked "Invite Attendees", and it shows my default email `a@mail.example.net` filled as a required attendee, but grayed out. I expected this to say `c@mail.example.net` because I had selected the `C` calendar, which should be associated with the `c@mail.example.net` email address. I don't see any option to change the "send from" address.

Is there some way in Lightning way to control which email address is used to send event invitations?